# Extra bytes allocated for custom class array when destructor defined

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I was trying out the code shown below:

```
class Example {
public:
    Example(int val = 0) : m_val(val) { }
    ~Example() { }

    void* operator new (std::size_t sz) { 
        std::cout << "Example created on the heap with size " << sz << std::endl;
        return std::malloc(sz);
    }

    void* operator new[] (std::size_t sz) { 
        std::cout << "Example created on the heap with size " << sz << std::endl;
        return std::malloc(sz);
    }

    void operator delete (void* ptr) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Deleted from the heap" << std::endl;
        std::free(ptr);
    }

    void operator delete[] (void* ptr) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Deleted from the heap" << std::endl;
        std::free(ptr);
    }
private:
    int m_val;
};
```

From main, I tried to test `new[]` operator by calling below snippet from `main`

```
    Example* p_example = new Example[4];
```

The output which was expected is 16, i.e. 4 times the `sizeof(int)` (since the class has only a 4 byte `m_val` member variable). However the output on the terminal was:

```
Example created on the heap with size 24
```

Now, when I **comment out** the **destructor** of the class, the output comes out to be what one would expect for it. Thus output with commented destructor is:

```
Example created on the heap with size 16
```

I eliminated the possibility of an extra 8 bytes allocated for the `vtable` pointer by adding a virtual function. In this case, the total memory allocated was an extra of 8 bytes over the original (which was 24 bytes), so the 8 bytes of memory which were being allocated extra are still being allocated so I believe that this is not as a result of inheritance.

I'm not able to figure out where the extra 8 bytes are allocated in this particular example, so any hints on the same would be appreciated. I tried using gdb to debug and see if any extra variables were present somewhere, but I couldn't notice anything out of the ordinary.
Thanks!

Comment: I guess that, when using a non-trival destructor, allocating an array needs a little more space to store the length of the array. We need to know the length when we delete the array so that the destructor can be called the right amount of times on the right objects. (I'm not completely sure, though.)

Comment: @chi I looked at the bytes, and the extra 8 are usually 0, sometimes seemingly garbage, definitely not a count.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Yes, it's a count (a `std::size_t`) that's placed first in case you have a user defined (non-`default`) destructor _or_ even if you remove the destructor (or `default` it) and your class contains non-trivially destructible member variables. In that case, it needs to know how many elements to loop through and call the destructor on each.